# How add debounce ( delay ) time on search filter ? Javascript

Tags: javascript

All code example is here:

I need to add debounce time for this search ( on every keyup delay )  ?
Like keyup. For every maybe 0.5 second delay.

```
var searchRequest = null;

$(function () {
    var minlength = 3;

    $("#sample_search").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();
         console.log('value', value)
        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            if (searchRequest != null) 
                searchRequest.abort();
            searchRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
                data: {
                    'search_keyword' : value
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                    if (value==$(that).val()) {
                      console.log('value real' , msg)
                    //Receiving the result of search here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the code below.

```js
$("#sample_search").keyup(function() {
    // If the user kept typing. Delete the previous timeout.
    clearTimeout(delayTime);

    // call 'ajaxCall' function after 500ms
    var delayTime = setTimeout(ajaxCall, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setTimeout()` function:

```
$(function () {
                var minlength = 3;

                $("#sample_search").keyup(function () {
                    var that = this,
                        value = $(this).val();
                    console.log('value', value);
                    if (value.length >= minlength ) {
                        if (searchRequest != null)
                            searchRequest.abort();

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            
                            searchRequest = $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
                                data: {
                                    'search_keyword' : value
                                },
                                dataType: "text",
                                success: function(msg){
                                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                                    if (value==$(that).val()) {
                                        console.log('value real' , msg)
                                        //Receiving the result of search here
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            
                        }, 500);
                                                
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Might be good idea to also add a disable to the button clicked during the debounce time, gives user the sense that it can not spam the button and also it prevents them from even trying. Still add @AmirBll solution though.

Comment: Yes this is work good. But one more think yet.. How to filter this data by search criteria ?